# Unable to get result using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a html page

I want to extract all  tags "href" attribute value.

Below is the html page:

```
<div class="universal">
<div class="slider">
    <a class="focus" href="/1295%2C"><div><div><div>St</div></div></div></a>,
    <a class="focus" href="/2395%2C"><div><div><div>GT</div></div></div></a>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <a class="focus" href="/3495%2C"><div><div><div>KT</div></div></div></a>,
    <a class="focus" href="/4595%2C"><div><div><div>LT</div></div></div></a>
</div>
<div class="slider">
    <a class="focus" href="/5695%2C"><div><div><div>OT</div></div></div></a>,
    <a class="focus" href="/6795%2C"><div><div><div>OT</div></div></div></a>,
    <a class="focus" href="/7895%2C"><div><div><div>OT</div></div></div></a>
</div>
```

I tried with below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = html_page
html_text = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
shows = html_text.find('div', {'class': 'slider'}).findAll('a', {'class': 'focus'})

urls = []
for a_tag in shows :
    urls.append(a_tag.find('a', {'class': 'focus'}).attrs['href'])
print urls
```

It gives None type of object has no attribute 'findAll'
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `find_all`.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
shows = html_text.find_all('div', {'class': 'slider'})

urls = []
for div in shows:
    for a_tag in div.find_all('a', {'class': 'focus'}):
        urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])
print urls
```

**Output:**

```
[u'/1295%2C', u'/2395%2C', u'/3495%2C', u'/4595%2C', u'/5695%2C', u'/6795%2C', u'/7895%2C']
```

Comment: @Rajesh, what have I missed ?

Comment: `findAll` --> `find_all` And also the for-loop was a little wrong.

Comment: @Rajesh, findAll is working.. I have checked it. yes for loop was incorrect